# (Unity) How to get generic component class from GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, gameobject

How to get a generic component from spawned GameObject In Unity?

I.e i have a base generic class:

```
class Base<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Foo() {}
}
```

and derived class:

```
class Example : Base<Example>
{

}
```

And I wonder to get this class from spawned GameObject where I attached it as a component.

I was tried this but my result was null so I decided to ask for some help :)

```
// @object - Spawned before and exists.
Base<MonoBehaviour> tmp = @object.GetComponent<Base<MonoBehaviour>>();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use interface implementation:

```
class Base<T> : MonoBehaviour, IBase where T : MonoBehaviour
```

And get interface from GO:

```
var tmp = @object.GetComponent<IBase>();
```